# Code-behind div content via jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I am trying to load a div content (that is getting filled from C# code-behind) using jQuery dialog.

The dialog comes up, but the content is empty.  Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#divMessages').dialog({
             autoOpen:false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    window.location.reload();
                }

            }

        });
    });  

    function showDialog(id) { 
        $('#' + id).dialog("open");
    }

<div id="divMessages" style="display:block;" runat="server" >   

</div>
```

C# Code-Behind:

```
divMessages.InnerHtml = "Error";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Failure", "showDialo  
('divMessages')",  true);
```

Comment: Is there content inside "divMessages" after the page loads?

Comment: yes, I am filling the div from code-behind